# Converting es6 script to JS using gulp

Tags: gulp, gulp-babel

I am trying to convert the ES6 code to simple JS, using babel in gulp. Running the below code I am getting [Error in Plugin "gulp-babel"] with Message: [Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions.]

```
  var gulp = require('gulp');
  var babel = require('gulp-babel');
  gulp.task('scripts',function(){
      return gulp.src(['src/scripts/app.js'])
      .pipe(babel({presets:['es2015']}))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('build/scripts/'))
  });
```

src/scripts/app.js

```
const hello = (name) => {
    return `hello ${name}`; 
};
```

Guiding me to convert the ES6 code to vanilla JS would be most appreciated.

Comment: The code worked for the following version combinations "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0"
  }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably using Babel 7, and your preset is not compatible with it. You should install and use `{ presets: ["@babel/preset-env"] }`.

Comment: yes got it. it is due to the mismatched versions of the dependencies.   
thank you!

Comment: also changed the code as mentioned by @TheDancingCode