# Error in plugin gulp-babel: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, npm, babeljs, package.json

I'm trying to use JavaScript 2015 (ES6) now in my Ionic v1 app:

package.json

```
 {
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@ionic-native/deeplinks": "^4.18.0",
    "cordova-android": "7.0.0",
    "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": "1.2.1",
    "cordova-common": "1.5.1",
    "cordova-plugin-app-event": "1.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-datepicker": "git+https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker.git",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-google-analytics": "1.7.11",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "5.3.2",
    "de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification": "0.8.5",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "4.2.2",
    "ionic-native": "^2.9.0",
    "ionic-plugin-deeplinks": "^1.0.17",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "2.2.1",
    "parse-push-plugin": "^1.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "bower": "1.3.3",
    "gulp": "3.8.10",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-concat": "2.2.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "0.3.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-rename": "1.2.0",
    "gulp-sass": "2.2.0",
    "gulp-util": "2.2.14",
    "ionic-minify": "2.0.10",
    "shelljs": "0.3.0"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-camera",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
    "cordova-plugin-datepicker",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information",
    "de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification",
    "parse-push-plugin@1.0.7",
    "cordova-plugin-google-analytics@1.7.11",
    "cordova-custom-config",
    "ionic-plugin-deeplinks"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "android"
  ],
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-datepicker": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification": {},
      "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION": "26"
      },
      "parse-push-plugin": {},
      "cordova-plugin-google-analytics": {},
    },
    "platforms": []
  }
}
```

gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var babel = require("gulp-babel");
var plumber = require("gulp-plumber");
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

var paths = {
  es6: ['./src/es6/*.js'],
  sass: ['./scss/**/*.scss']
};

gulp.task('default', ['babel', 'sass']);

gulp.task("babel", function () {
  return gulp.src(paths.es6)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(babel({presets: ['es2015']}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("www/js"));
});

gulp.task('sass', function(done) {
    gulp.src('./scss/ionic.app.scss')
      .pipe(sass())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
      .pipe(minifyCss({
        keepSpecialComments: 0
      }))
      .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
      .on('end', done);
  });


gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.es6, ['babel']);
  gulp.watch(paths.sass, ['sass']);
});
```

And while running "gulp babel" I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in plugin "gulp-babel"
Message:
    Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions.
```

I'm pretty sure that it is related to wrong versions in devDependencies.

I tried to change version, but keep getting errors.

I would really appreciate if someone can help me solve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting es6 script to JS using gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54087389/converting-es6-script-to-js-using-gulp)

Comment: Thanks! I made it work by changing to "gulp-babel": "^7.0.0"

Answer (score 4):

I made it work by changing to "gulp-babel": "^7.0.0"

Comment: Did work for me - im already on version 8  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
    "require-dir": "^1.2.0"
  }